# Not enough quota is available to process this command. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070718) in windows 8 metro app for GRID(Not for GRIDVIEW)

Tags: xaml, windows-8, grid, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml

I am trying to generate dynamic controls in grid through UI  where am dynamically specifying the size of controls. while generating more then 1500 control it is throwing this error "Not enough quota is available to process this command. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070718) " . i have seen some solution for gridview for the same exception but i am using GRID so not beneficial for me .

please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

```
     <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollMode="Auto" 
              HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
              VerticalScrollMode="Auto"
              VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="232,10,267,0" Grid.Row="1">
                <Grid Name="dynamicgrid" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="LightBlue"   Height="Auto" Width="Auto" Grid.Row="1"/>

        </ScrollViewer>
C# code 
 try
            {
                MainPage mainpage = (MainPage)e.Parameter;
                buttons = Convert.ToInt32(mainpage.buttonsize);
                textblock = Convert.ToInt32(mainpage.txtBlocksize);
                textbox = Convert.ToInt32(mainpage.txtBoxsize);
                rows = Convert.ToInt32(mainpage.rows);
                buttonwidth = Convert.ToInt32(mainpage.buttonwidth);
                textblockwidth = Convert.ToInt32(mainpage.txtBlockwidth);
                textboxwidth = Convert.ToInt32(mainpage.txtBoxwidth);
                grdcolumn = buttons + textblock + textbox;


                for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
                {
                    RowDefinition rowDef = new RowDefinition();
                    rowDef.Height = new GridLength(200, GridUnitType.Auto);
                    dynamicgrid.RowDefinitions.Add(rowDef);

                }
                for (int j = 0; j < grdcolumn; j++) //need to mention
                {
                    ColumnDefinition colDef1 = new ColumnDefinition();
                    colDef1.Width = new GridLength(100, GridUnitType.Auto);
                    dynamicgrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(colDef1);
                }

                for (textboxcolumncount = 0; textboxcolumncount < textbox; textboxcolumncount++)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)//textbox
                    {
                        TextBox txtbox = new TextBox();
                        txtbox.SetValue(TextBox.TextProperty, "txtbox" + i.ToString());
                        txtbox.Width = textboxwidth;
                        txtbox.Height = 50;
                        txtbox.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, textboxcolumncount);
                        txtbox.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, i);
                        dynamicgrid.Children.Add(txtbox);
                        dynamicgrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = GridLength.Auto });

                    }
                }
                textboxcolumncount = textbox;
                for (textblockcolumncount = textboxcolumncount; textblockcolumncount < (grdcolumn - (buttons)); textblockcolumncount++)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
                    {
                        TextBlock txtblock = new TextBlock();
                        txtblock.SetValue(TextBlock.NameProperty, "txtblock" + i.ToString());
                        txtblock.Width = textblockwidth;
                        txtblock.Height = 50;
                        txtblock.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, textblockcolumncount);
                        txtblock.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, i);
                        txtblock.Text = "TextBlock" + i.ToString();
                        txtblock.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
                        dynamicgrid.Children.Add(txtblock);
                        dynamicgrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = GridLength.Auto });

                    }
                }
                textboxcolumncount = textblockcolumncount;
                for (buttonCoulmncount = textboxcolumncount; buttonCoulmncount < (grdcolumn); buttonCoulmncount++)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) //button
                    {

                        Button btn = new Button();
                        btn.SetValue(Button.NameProperty, "btn" + i.ToString());
                        btn.Content = "Button" + i.ToString();
                        btn.Width = textboxwidth;
                        btn.Height = 50;
                        btn.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
                        btn.SetValue(Grid.RowProperty, i);
                        btn.SetValue(Grid.ColumnProperty, buttonCoulmncount);
                        dynamicgrid.Children.Add(btn);
                        dynamicgrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition() { Height = GridLength.Auto });

                    }
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;

            }
```

Comment: Is there a strong reason you are using a Grid/cells?  Why not use an ItemsControl (or GridView/ListView) then allow you to put the DataTemplate there and let the template do the work.  What you are seeing is a massive amount of UI elements being created and you are hitting a windows PostMessage limit because you are not virtualizing any of the UI.

Answer (score 0):

Go through this Link I am not sure wether this will solve your problem or you will have an idea of it.

[Not enough quota ex](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/d778c6e0-c248-4a1a-9391-28d038247578/mysterious-not-enough-quota-is-available-to-process-this-command-in-winrt-port-of-datagrid)

After that you can make a search. I still have not found any issue like this. Guess have to Replicate the code on the system. :)